# Multiple Replace within on query

Tags: sql, replace

All of my data contains " at the end and the start. For example  "0251716474".

I would like to use a replace function on all of this data and I am able to do them individually :

```
select replace (column_name1, '"',' ')FROM TBL_NAME;
select replace (column_name2, '"',' ')FROM TBL_NAMe;
```

and this doesn't work

```
select replace (bf_id, '"',' ') and replace (contact_telphone, '"',' ') 
FROM CJ_GC_LAPSED_29082018;
```

Any tips?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  That is very vague.

Comment: Apologies. the error is invalid identifier. I would like it to bring back the data without the " in both of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `,` instead in `SELECT` statement :

```
SELECT REPLACE(bf_id, '"',' ') , REPLACE(contact_telphone, '"',' ') 
-------------------------------^
FROM CJ_GC_LAPSED_29082018;
```

Comment: I apologies I miss typed something.Cheers for the help!